# Should I flag answers and comments that could lead into a wrong usage?

Tags: discussion, answers

I was into this question, where a user was trying to achieve something that will result in an invalid source code (in this case invalid HTML):

[How can I put HTML table inside a dropdownbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13383937/1456376)

There was a comment that said "*try it and see what happens*". There was also an answer with a solution. And as the solution might create the requested markup using JavaScript, it will still be invalid.

So should I flag answers like that or is it OK to just leave a comment?

Comment: Do not flag answers because they are wrong. The correct action is to downvote and comment.

Comment: Of course you're right on how to deal with it. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, if anything a powerful comment is much more effective than a downvote. Most users can't see that there are downvotes unless it's negative. And those that can, need to click to see it. So a comment is many times more effective at "destroying" an answer than a downvote.

Comment: Yeah, I really don't like to downvote. I actually leave a comment all the time instead. Sometimes even to explain other peoples downvotes who missed to leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Moderators aren't there to delete incorrect things. If an answer is incorrect or will produce incorrect results, downvote it and explain why they shouldn't use it. If a comment is leading someone in the wrong direction, post a comment of your own explaining why they shouldn't follow that advice.

Comment: Clear an simple explanation, And you're right. It's not a moderator's task. I could have come up with this myself. Thanks.

Comment: Note, we have a specific decline reason for this: "flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer"